# How to implement maximum login attempts while not using default LoginController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to prevent user login more than let's say 3 times. I know that there's a trait `ThrottlesLogins`. I also know that I can set everything in `hasTooManyLoginAttempts`. But what if my app works differently and I did not created auth via `make:auth` command (I don't have LoginController). How should I use this `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` method?

I've tried to add the following into my login method:

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
      $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
      return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yah you can do it , keep a field login_attempt in your table . 
and check the count if he fails upadate the field 1. and then check his 
login attempt.

$attempt = User::where('id',$userid)->first();
if($attempt->login_attempt == 3){
  //write your code for inactive user or block the user
 }else{
  //redirect to dashboard
 }
```